# ubuntu won't load, shows sceen with GNU GRUB

Tags: grub2, dual-boot

I downloaded Ubuntu 12.10 to run alongside windows, and when I start the computer up, I get the "Please select operating system" screen, and I choose Ubuntu. However, I don't see anything that looks like Ubuntu, (or at least not what it was like in the online tour) and I get a screen that shows something like:

Try (h0,0): NTFS5:

for a split second, then shows:

fâ~ ▲0000h

for another second, then it shows:

```
                         GNU                  GRUB 2.00-7ubuntu4
```

Minimal BASH-like editing is supported. For the first word TAB lists possible command completions. Anywhere else TAB lists possible device or file completions.

grub>_

I am new to Ubuntu, (and therefore have not gone on it) and am not knowledgeable in code, so I don't know what I need to do. I have checked around, and I think that I am missing something, possibly Grub2. If so, how do I get it?

Comment: I am doing something similar HERE!!! http://askubuntu.com/questions/366001/ubuntu-13-10-grub-2-0

Answer (score 0):

Its either the computer has a faulty CPU, or it doesn't like Ubuntu.

Possible Solution 1: Try to access the kernel recovery modes in grub (I believe it is the second option), if the computer allows you, select the 'resume normal boot' option. Normally this should work. (I have a laptop that simply couldn't boot into Ubuntu normally, but this method worked.)

If it does have a fault in the hardware that is causing it, there isn't that much you can do but replace it.

Hope this helps.